# Request for translation help (English to Portuguese)

Tags: discussion, languages, internationalization

This isn’t really a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) question, but I’ve no better idea for the required tag.

Can someone translate my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562688/funcoes-sequencias-functions-sequence) into Portuguese? The OP’s reading knowledge of English isn’t up to following the answer, and his English production is nearly non-existent, so he’s asked me to make the request for him.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I’ve now been sent a translation, by someone who prefers to remain anonymous, and have added it to the answer. My thanks to the translator.

Comment: Funny, was this a moderator? I don't see how Private Messages work otherwise.

Comment: @Ahaan: The translator? No, it was someone who requested and was given an e-mail address for me in comments that were subsequently deleted.

Comment: Ah, makes sense.